# android mediaplayer start called in state1

Tags: android, buffer, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an audio file when the app started, but I am getting an error says that `start called in state 1` `Error (-38,0)`, here is my code:

```
public void audioPlayer(){
        //set up MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.create(this, R.raw.music);
            onPrepared(mp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void audioPlayer(){
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(mListener);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(this, R.raw.music);
        mp.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private OnPreparedListener mListener=new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
};
```